# listening only to one event at a time in chrome extension background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i want the init() function to be called only one time even if the two events were triggered

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function callback() {
  init();
});
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function callback() {
  init();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track it with a variable.

```
let initCalled = false;
```

Then in your `init()` function:

```
function init() {
    if (initCalled) return;
    //rest of init() code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a named function for both events and unregister both events inside.

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(initOnce);
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(initOnce);

function initOnce() {
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(initOnce);
  chrome.tabs.onActivated.removeListener(initOnce);
  init();
}
```